# show related articles in single.php template

Tags: wp-query, single

How I can show inside the `single.php` template the related articles? Is there any particular params I can use with `WP_Query` or `get_posts()` ?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "related". WordPress has no concept of related articles. It could mean the same category, same tags, similar content and words, articles the the same users read, almost anything. So it depends on what you want.

Comment: I mean articles from the same category, I've done a `var_dump()` and I see that into the `$post` object there isn't the category so I don't know how to create the custom query